# Using shopify admin API, orderSendInvoice how to send invoice email to multiple recipients

Tags: shopify, payment, invoice

After creating an order, to collect payment via Invoice, using orderInvoiceSend mutation https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql/2023-07/mutations/orderInvoiceSend

Here we can only use one email address in "to". How can I use multiple "cc" email address so that more than only one person can see the Invoice sent to the email.

From the Shopify invoicing GUI functionality, we can select multiple recipients for sending invoices. So using API, can't we achieve the same?